# align image to left in angularjs html

Tags: html, angularjs, angular-material

You can see rows in picture.

[image: those are rows]

This is code of that view:

```
<div layout="row" layout-align="space-around center" >
<product-image-thumbnail layout="row" layout-align="left center"
    src="vm.callFunction(field)"
    setter="vm.callFunction(value)" />

<md-button  ng-click="vm.onMouseOver(field.getSrc))" layout="row" layout-align="right center">
    <md-icon>zoom_in</md-icon>
</md-button>
</div>
```

I want to align image or uploadanimage to left, zoom button to right.

But it doesnot work.

i also tried

```
layout-align="start start
 layout-align="end end"
```

but it did not do the job.

Also i tried buttons to convert to `column` but it is same.

it makes two rows if i dont put first layout. i need them inside a row.

this is where src image comes

```
<div ng-show="!vm.src" layout="row">
    <md-button class="md-button md-ink-ripple" ng-click="vm.Dialog($event)">
        <md-icon>file_upload</md-icon>
        <span translate>upload_image</span>
    </md-button>
</div>
<div ng-show="vm.src" class="thumbnail" layout="column" layout-align="center center" flex layout-padding ng-click="vm.Dialog($event)">
    <img src="{{vm.src}}" style="max-height: 60px;max-width: 60px"
         error-src="content/images/no_image_icon.gif"
    />
</div>
```

Comment: You have (second row) `...layout-align="left center"`. May be worth trying only `...layout-align="left"`.

Comment: I just tried, i wish it worked but did not :(

Comment: what is product-image? directive?

Answer (score 1):

```html
<p>This is some text. <img src="smiley.gif" alt="Smiley face" width="42" height="42" align="left"> This is some text.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use angular material, try using the space-between param. [Example Plunker.](https://plnkr.co/edit/4RiRBUfPFpugPvxfKNSg)

```
<div><!-- shouldn't need layout here-->
    <img layout="row" layout-align="space-between center"  />
    <button layout="row" layout-align="space-between center">Zoom</button>
</div>
```

Comment: it makes two rows if i dont put first layout. i need them inside a row.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way,

```
<section layout="row" layout-align="end center" layout-wrap>
    <div layout="row" layout-align="start center" flex>
      <img src="https://echtemaaltijd.blob.core.windows.net/image/image_671ed3d3-0c1e-43d5-9e9a-86247556fd00" class="md-card-image" alt="Washed Out">
      <span flex></span>
    </div>
    <md-button class="md-warn">Type</md-button>
  </section>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/7PDYrSnUoNzPFadjzKAb?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try this with flex!

```
<div layout="row" layout-alignment="stretch">
    <product-image-thumbnail flex
        src="vm.callFunction(field)"
        setter="vm.callFunction(value)" />

    <md-button  ng-click="vm.onMouseOver(field.getSrc))" flex="5">
        <md-icon>zoom_in</md-icon>
    </md-button>
</div>
```

The `flex` Will take up as much space as it can till 95% of the available width and `flex=5` will ensure it is 5$